# How can I swap (as in alias) command names in zsh?

Tags: zsh

If I try

```
$ alias pwd=echo
$ alias echo=pwd
```

I get

```
$ pwd
/home/owen
$ echo hi
hi
```

It seems aliases are followed recursively. Perhaps if there was a way to stop the recursion, that would work. In this example I can use `builtin`, but that won't work in general, particular for `-g` aliases.

Answer (score 1):

All you want is that your commands are expanded once.

As describe in [the zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Aliasing); you can prevent an alias expansion by quoting.

This should do the trick

```
$ alias pwd="\echo" ; alias echo="\pwd"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do the equivalent of using `builtin` for commands which aren't built-in shell commands

The first is to just use the full path for the command you get from `which`. For example,

```
> which cat
/bin/cat
> /bin/cat
```

will  run `cat`, ignoring any alias you may have set up.

The other option is to use `/usr/bin/env`. For example,

```
> /usr/bin/env cat
```

will also run `cat` while ignoring any alias to `cat` you may have set up.